# How to find un-synced content on my iPhone

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, iphone, software-update

iTunes is telling me there's updated iOS firmware available (4.3.5) for my iPhone 3GS.

I've synced the iPhone to iTunes already. Repeated the sync several times.

Regardless of this, every time I go to apply the firmware update I get the following warning from iTunes:

[image: iTunes Purchased items warning]

I'm uncertain how this can be as I've most definitely completed a successful sync. How can I figure out what remains un-synced from my iPhone to iTunes so I can resolve this and apply the firmware update?

Edit: I'm not interested in whether I can safely ignore this warning and apply the iOS upgrade. I want to know how I figure out what's triggering the warning. What content does iTunes identify as unsynced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to File -> Transfer Purchases.

That way you know for sure the purchases have been transferred over.

Comment: Done. But I still get the warning message from iTunes when I click the `Update` button to apply the new firmware.

Comment: Well, as long as your transfers are over just go for it. As of right now all music, apps and books can be re-downloaded thanks to iCloud so you won't be losing any of that. The only thing you might be losing is videos. So make sure you have all of those backed up before going ahead with it.

Comment: You've missed the point of the question I'm afraid. It isn't whether I can safely ignore this warning, but how I go about finding the unsynced content that's triggering it.

Comment: Do you get any errors or warning after "transfer purchases" completes?

Comment: @zelag: no errors. Says it completed successfully.

Comment: Mine cleared up after I did "transfer purchases".  By following the progress indicator in iTunes, it seems that the untransferred purchases were paid (non-free) apps.  I had been looking for a way to sync those before, but didn't find anything like it in the Store section.  Am I missing something or is this the only way to keep the paid apps synced?  (And why doesn't the error dialog explain this, if it's this simple?)

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the privilege to comment on Chris' answer, so posting here (I agree that Transfer Purchases should do it). You could always check your purchase history in iTunes and your emailed receipts for purchases and compare this against the actual items in your library, but that's a lot of work. Maybe it's worth doing just for your most recent purchases. (The history in iTunes for multiple items purchased on the same day only lists the first few purchases, so the list in iTunes may not be complete without the receipts they mail you.)